# How to execute multiple python files using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

```
# file1.py
@pytest.mark.add
def m1():
  print("Adding")

# file2.py
@pytest.mark.divide
def m2():
print("Dividing")
```

Can we execute above two files simultaneously with one line command in pycharm using terminal

Comment: Just testing on my side, I presume you've [registered your custom markers](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#registering-markers)?

Comment: `pytest file1.py file2.py`?

Comment: I tried it ,but it is taking only one file. Do we need to add any "," or ";"  between files ?